# Paypal Sandbox Error #10548: Invalid Configuration

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I setup a test Magento site with paypal payment pro on a sandbox account, sandbox account does have business-pro enable, when I test my first transaction, everything was good, order create and sandbox payment received, but when I'm testing again with same test credit number or others provided by paypal, I'm now getting this #10548: Invalid Configuration error.

I know that usually this error occur when the account is not business pro enabled, but I recheck again and it is enabled, I even create 2 more merchant test account with business pro enabled and still get the same error. Why did first transaction was OK and now it can't process?

Answer (score 0):

To validate that this doesnt have anything to do with an isssue on your end, I would recommend you to use this site http://chadcaples.com/index.php/classic-api-s/nvp-quick-test

Enter your sandbox API credentials, sandbox mode and choose DoDirectPayment API. If you didnt receive any error, the issue might be on your end.

If even using this site you still receive the error, can you post the full response?

Comment: Same error, look like there's a problem on paypal end with sandbox account on pro, here's the response
API Response:
TIMESTAMP=2018-02-26T20:43:21Z
CORRELATIONID=ac854d367f90
ACK=Failure
VERSION=82.0
BUILD=39206242
L_ERRORCODE0=10548
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid Configuration
L_LONGMESSAGE0=This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
AMT=5.00
CURRENCYCODE=USD

Comment: seems like there is no issue with the API call. but more of an account issue.
Could you try with these credentials:
API USERNAME: testingonlyaccount_api1.gmail.com
API PASSWORD: GXLV5N8KMELXPPGF
API SIGNATURE: AB4D1gCIktIekr43tuy.8HapuNzkAJtaozk-tReBAhNLept9zxKMSIJb